# Unauthorized website restriction when redirecting a Flows to a public website

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, visual-workflow

I have a public website based on Flows,
The page is basically:

```
<apex:page>
<flow:interview name="Pre_Course" buttonLocation="bottom"/>
</apex:page>
```

At the end of the Flow, when the user hits the finish button,
The flow goes back to the starting point,
So I decided to add a public URL the user would be redirected to,

Let’s say for example, but that’s not the website I’m using: Google.com

```
<apex:page>
<flow:interview name="Pre_Course" buttonLocation="bottom" finishLocation="{!URLFOR('http://www.google.com')}"/>
</apex:page>
```

But when I click on Finish, 
I get an unauthorized website restriction, must login!

Or when i run the page within Salesforce, i get the following error:

Invalid Page Redirection: The page you attempted to access has been blocked due to a redirection to an outside website or an improperly coded link or button. Please contact your salesforce.com Administrator for assistance.

What permissions do I need to add to my Sites “Public Access Settings”?

Comment: Perhaps you need to add the website to "remote site settings"? Try it out and let me know. I know that the system ordinarily restricts inter-domain redirects as a matter of security. Also, I'm not entirely convinced you need to use URLFOR at all.

Comment: Well i tried it and it didn't work, but i'm not sure if i need to deactivate the website and then reactivate again. But could you please explain your comment about URLFOR? do you have another suggestion how to do it?

Comment: So i ran the page inside salesforce and it tells me: Invalid Page Redirection
The page you attempted to access has been blocked due to a redirection to an outside website or an improperly coded link or button. Please contact your salesforce.com Administrator for assistance.

Comment: URLFOR is best used with $Action or $Page global variables. For a normal redirection, a normal URL should work just fine, assuming its allowed. I don't know if there is a way to redirect using flows.

Comment: Yes i think its not possible too, but i submitted a case with Salesforce just to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

After working with a Salesforce rep and her co-corkers, they concluded that this cannot be done.

The rep first started by saying that it is possible to do what i want, and she did all the testing herself, and after a few hours working on it and discussing the issue with her coworkers, they all concluded that it can not be done

Comment: Could you please clean this up with some additional details? Did they tell you why it can't be done, or if it's on the roadmap? Any other information such as a case number, etc? As a prior Technical Support representative, I know that support often doesn't have all the answers in front of them or all available resources to test with, so sometimes a "this is impossible" answer isn't actually impossible. Some supporting documentation that states this would help.

Comment: Well the rep first started by saying that it is possible to do what i want, and she did all the testing herself, and after a few hours working on it and discussing the issue with her coworkers, they all concluded that it can not be done.

Comment: Pg. 211 of the Winter '14 Visualforce Developer's Guide: "You can't redirect flow users to a URL that’s external to your Salesforce organization."

Answer (score 0):

that's right the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_flows_finishlocation.htm) does say this:

> You can't redirect flow users to a URL that’s external to your Salesforce org.

We are tweaking this a bit to have a Visualforce page as the `finishLocation`.

```
<flow:interview name="My_Flow" interview="{!flow}" finishLocation="{!$Page.RedirectPage}"
```

Then have the `RedirectPage` setup like this:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" controller="RedirectPageCtrl" action="{!redirectExternally}">
    Please wait, redirecting...
</apex:page>
```

Then have the controller redirect it:

```
public PageReference redirectExternally() {
    PageReference pr = new PageReference('https://www.google.com/');
    pr.setRedirect(true);

    return pr;
}
```

It would have the annoying affect of users seeing a temporary page flash before being redirected, but if you are okay with it, then it works.